# grails 3 rest-api profile GET

Tags: rest, grails-3.1

I am using grails 3 rest-api profile. I created generated simple domain class

```
@Resource(readOnly = false, formats = ['json', 'xml'])
class User {
    String name
    String address
    Date dateOfBirth
}
```

while http://localhost:8080/user/ will give me back json list of users, if I try http://localhost:8080/user/1 if gives back :

```
{"message":"Not Found","error":404}
```

what gives ?

Comment: I have the same problem. Which version do you use? Mine is 3.1.1

Answer (score 3):

actually I since found out that the url exposed is /user/show/1

since RestResource automatically exposes a controller based on grails.rest.RestfulController you can look in that class for the full list of methods

Answer (score 0):

seems to be a bug. If you specify a `uri` it works:

```
@Resource(uri='/user/', readOnly = false, formats = ['json', 'xml'])
class User {
    String name
    String address
    Date dateOfBirth
}
```